# I need help refactoring for error handling in Rust

Tags: error-handling, rust, refactoring, rust-cargo

I would like to refactor this Rust code for calculating the largest series product and make it as efficient and elegant as possible. I feel that

```
lsp(string_digits: &str, span: usize) -> Result<u64, Error>
```

could be done in a way to make it much more elegant than it is right now. Could lsp be implemented with only one series of chained iterator methods?

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
pub enum Error {
    SpanTooLong,
    InvalidDigit(char),
}

fn sp(w: &[u8]) -> u64 {
    w.iter().fold(1u64, |acc, &d| acc * u64::from(d))
}

pub fn lsp(string_digits: &str, span: usize) -> Result<u64, Error> {
    let invalid_chars = string_digits
        .chars()
        .filter(|ch| !ch.is_numeric())
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
    if span > string_digits.len() {
        return Err(Error::SpanTooLong);
    } else if !invalid_chars.is_empty() {
        return Err(Error::InvalidDigit(invalid_chars[0]));
    } else if span == 0 || string_digits.is_empty() {
        return Ok(1);
    }

    let vec_of_u8_digits = string_digits
        .chars()
        .map(|ch| ch.to_digit(10).unwrap() as u8)
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
    let lsp = vec_of_u8_digits
        .windows(span)
        .max_by(|&w1, &w2| sp(w1).cmp(&sp(w2)))
        .unwrap();
    Ok(sp(lsp))
}
```

Comment: There isn't a concrete question here other than asking us to review your code. This might be a better fit for Code Review SE.

Comment: @E_net4 Sorry for my seemingly toxic behavior. I had never used that part of SE before, I'll make sure to check it out for future inquiries.

Comment: Don't worry, there was nothing toxic in your behavior. :) I was simply concerned about the question's fitness on this site.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I perform iterator computations over iterators of Results without collecting to a temporary vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48841367/how-do-i-perform-iterator-computations-over-iterators-of-results-without-collect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the most elegant way, but I've given it a try, hope the new version is equivalent to the given program.

Two things will be needed in this case: First, we need a data structure that provides the sliding window "on the fly" and second a function that ends the iteration early if the conversion yields an error.

For the former I've chosen a VecDeque since `span` is dynamic. For the latter there is a function called [`process_results`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.8.0/itertools/structs/struct.ProcessResults.html) in the itertools crate. It converts an iterator over results to an iterator over the unwrapped type and stops iteration if an error is encountered.

I've also slightly changed the signature of `sp` to accept any iterator over u8.

This is the code:

```rust
use std::collections::VecDeque;
use itertools::process_results;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
pub enum Error {
    SpanTooLong,
    InvalidDigit(char),
}

fn sp(w: impl Iterator<Item=u8>) -> u64 {
    w.fold(1u64, |acc, d| acc * u64::from(d))
}

pub fn lsp(string_digits: &str, span: usize) -> Result<u64, Error> {
    if span > string_digits.len() {
        return Err(Error::SpanTooLong);
    } else if span == 0 || string_digits.is_empty() {
        return Ok(1);
    }

    let mut init_state = VecDeque::new();
    init_state.resize(span, 0);

    process_results(string_digits.chars()
        .map(|ch| ch.to_digit(10)
            .map(|d| d as u8)
            .ok_or(Error::InvalidDigit(ch))),
        |digits|
            digits.scan(init_state, |state, digit| {
                state.pop_back();
                state.push_front(digit);
                Some(sp(state.iter().cloned()))
            })
            .max()
            .unwrap()
    )
}
```

Comment: This works for most cases, except for the case when all series products would produce 0. For instance, for lsp("99099") it would produce Ok(81) instead of Ok(0), that's because the state transition would be: [9] -> [9, 9] -> [0, 9, 9] -> [9, 0, 9] -> [9, 9, 0].

Comment: The solution would be to pad the first n states (the no. of states before the state.len() == span) with zeros, thus their sp would always be 0 and will not be counted into lsp.

Comment: As follows: `if state.len() == span {
                        state.pop_back();
                    } else {
                        for _i in 1..span {
                            state.push_front(0u8);
                        }
                    }`

Comment: Also, naming the parsed u8 digits as chars is very misleading :)

Comment: Other than that, great job +1

Comment: *correction: I meant lsp("99099", 3) for the example I gave.

Comment: Yep correct, I'll change the answer to reflect both the corner case and the name.