# How to have an iterator that returns Result<Vec<Vec<u32>>> instead return a flattened Result<Vec<u32>>?

Tags: vector, rust, iterator

I am trying to collect data into `Result<Vec_>>` from data that has nested vectors. Consider the following [code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=39f375612db84e9e99cf71d36e735f44):

```rust
type Result<T> = std::result::Result<T, String>;

fn f(x: u32) -> Result<Vec<u32>> {
    Ok(vec![x, x, x])
}

fn main() {
    let sources = [1, 2, 3];
    let out1: Vec<Result<Vec<u32>>> = sources.iter().map(|x| f(*x)).collect();
    let out2: Result<Vec<Vec<u32>>> = sources.iter().map(|x| f(*x)).collect();
    // let out3: Result<Vec<u32>> = sources.iter().map(|x| f(*x)).collect();
}
```

Both `out1` and `out2` compile correctly, but what I would really like to get is a variation of `out2` where the two nested vectors are flattened into one. If I try to use `out3`, I get the following error:

```
error[E0277]: a collection of type `std::vec::Vec<u32>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `std::vec::Vec<u32>`
  --> src/main.rs:11:64
   |
11 |     let out3: Result<Vec<u32>> = sources.iter().map(|x| f(*x)).collect();
   |                                                                ^^^^^^^ a collection of type `std::vec::Vec<u32>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=std::vec::Vec<u32>>`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::iter::FromIterator<std::vec::Vec<u32>>` is not implemented for `std::vec::Vec<u32>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::iter::FromIterator<std::result::Result<std::vec::Vec<u32>, std::string::String>>` for `std::result::Result<std::vec::Vec<u32>, std::string::String>`
```

How do I get to the flattened `Result<Vec<_>>` without building intermediate structures?

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [How do I perform iterator computations over iterators of Results without collecting to a temporary vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48841367/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: The duplicate applied to your case: `itertools::process_results(sources.iter().copied().map(f), |i| i.flatten().collect())`