# How to handle Result in flat_map

Tags: rust

I know we can use `collect` to move a `Result` from inner to outer, like:

```rust
fn produce_result(my_struct: &MyStruct) -> Result<MyStruct, Error>;

let my_results: Vec<MyStruct> = vec![];
let res = my_results.iter().map(|my_struct| produce_result(&my_struct)).collect::<Result<Vec<MyStruct>, Error>>;
```

which propagates error from the closure to the outer.

However, this method doesn't work in `flat_map` case ([Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=89f263b4dc8c279d524c40e34832606b)):

```rust
fn produce_result(my_struct: &MyStruct) -> Result<Vec<MyStruct>, Error>;

let my_results: Vec<MyStruct> = vec![];
let res = my_results.iter().flat_map(|my_struct| produce_result(&my_struct)).collect::<Result<Vec<MyStruct>, Error>>;
```

the compiler complains: "a collection of type `std::result::Result<std::vec::Vec<MyStruct>, Error>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `std::vec::Vec<MyStruct>`"

How to work around this case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I perform iterator computations over iterators of Results without collecting to a temporary vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48841367/how-do-i-perform-iterator-computations-over-iterators-of-results-without-collect) [How to do simple math with a list of numbers from a file and print out the result in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59243725/how-to-do-simple-math-with-a-list-of-numbers-from-a-file-and-print-out-the-resul)

Comment: The duplicate [results](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d3f7eea56fbbc4d8b6f1093e8266f096)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`flat_map` "flattens" the top-layer of the value returned from closure, by calling its `IntoIterator` implementation. It's important that it doesn't try to reach *inside* - i.e., if you had your own `MyResult`, it would error out on `flat_map` itself:

```
enum Error {}

enum MyResult<T, U> {
    Ok(T),
    Err(U),
}

struct MyStruct;

fn produce_result(item: &MyStruct) -> MyResult<Vec<MyStruct>, Error> {
    MyResult::Ok(vec![])
}

fn main() {
    let my_structs: Vec<MyStruct> = vec![];
    let res = my_structs
        .iter()
        .flat_map(|my_struct| produce_result(&my_struct))
        .collect::<Result<Vec<MyStruct>, Error>>();
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=947b45598521ab6a9b6172df4f6c98e0))

Error:

```
error[E0277]: `MyResult<std::vec::Vec<MyStruct>, Error>` is not an iterator
  --> src/main.rs:18:10
   |
18 |         .flat_map(|my_struct| produce_result(&my_struct))
   |          ^^^^^^^^ `MyResult<std::vec::Vec<MyStruct>, Error>` is not an iterator
   |
   = help: the trait `std::iter::Iterator` is not implemented for `MyResult<std::vec::Vec<MyStruct>, Error>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::iter::IntoIterator` for `MyResult<std::vec::Vec<MyStruct>, Error>`
```

In your case, however, the behaviour is different, since [`Result` implements `IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/core/result/enum.Result.html#impl-IntoIterator). This iterator yields `Ok` value unchanged and skips `Err`, so when `flat_map`ping the `Result`, you effectively ignore every error and only use the results of successful calls.

There is a way to fix it, although a but cumbersome. You should explicitly match on the `Result`, wrapping the `Err` case in the `Vec` and "distributing" the `Ok` case over the already-existing `Vec`, then let `flat_map` do its job:

```
let res = my_structs
    .iter()
    .map(|my_struct| produce_result(&my_struct))
    .flat_map(|result| match result {
        Ok(vec) => vec.into_iter().map(|item| Ok(item)).collect(),
        Err(er) => vec![Err(er)],
    })
    .collect::<Result<Vec<MyStruct>, Error>>();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=be6184f3d5b9ecbbd823d3853ae81038)

There's also another way, which might be more performant if errors are indeed present (even if only sometimes):

```
fn external_collect(my_structs: Vec<MyStruct>) -> Result<Vec<MyStruct>, Error> {
    Ok(my_structs
        .iter()
        .map(|my_struct| produce_result(&my_struct))
        .collect::<Result<Vec<_>, _>>()?
        .into_iter()
        .flatten()
        .collect())
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5cde133eb6c5f5de3120489aa58591df)

I've made some quick benchmarking - the code is [on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=c199bd93dbefcbe1d3bac804d1ec5bf0), too, although it can't be run there due to the absence of `cargo bench` command, so I've runned them locally. Here are the results:

```
test vec_result::external_collect_end_error   ... bench:   2,759,002 ns/iter (+/- 1,035,039)
test vec_result::internal_collect_end_error   ... bench:   3,502,342 ns/iter (+/- 438,603)

test vec_result::external_collect_start_error ... bench:          21 ns/iter (+/- 6)
test vec_result::internal_collect_start_error ... bench:          30 ns/iter (+/- 19)

test vec_result::external_collect_no_error    ... bench:   7,799,498 ns/iter (+/- 815,785)
test vec_result::internal_collect_no_error    ... bench:   3,489,530 ns/iter (+/- 170,124)
```

It seems that the version with two chained `collect`s takes double time of the method with nested `collect`s if the execution is successful, but is substantionally (by one third, approximately) faster when execution does short-circuit on some error. This result is consistent over multiple benchmark runs, so the large variance reported probably doesn't really matter.

Comment: This way works! Thank you. But I also wonder that I could also get the expected result by `my_structs.iter().map(...).collect::<Result<Vec<_>, _>>()?.iter().flatten().collect`, since both way needs more than one `collect`, which one is more efficient?

Comment: Get it. Thank you!

Comment: "test vec_result::external_collect_start_error ... bench:          21 ns/iter (+/- 6)
test vec_result::internal_collect_start_error ... bench:          30 ns/iter (+/- 19)" this is unlucky to be reel result, this obviously not run and optimized away by compiler.

Comment: @Stargateur Tried to move the error into second entry instead of first - got 61 ns and 62 ns correspondingly. Looks like compiler does short-circuiting at compile-time?

Comment: Thanks for this thorough answer! I think `.map(|item| Ok(item))` can be abbreviated to `.map(Ok)`.

Answer (score 5):

Using [itertools](https://crates.io/crates/itertools)' [flatten_ok](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.10.1/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.flatten_ok) method:

```
use itertools::Itertools;
use std::error::Error;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    // without error
    let res = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10]]
        .into_iter()
        .map(Ok::<_, &str>)
        .flatten_ok()
        .collect::<Result<Vec<_>, _>>()?;
    println!("{:?}", res);

    // with error
    let res = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10]]
        .into_iter()
        .map(|_| Err::<[i32; 2], _>("errored out"))
        .flatten_ok()
        .collect::<Result<Vec<_>, _>>()?;
    println!("{:?}", res); // not printed

    Ok(())
}
```

[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=beta&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2b7483be2a50608ea2a8aa9e0d07e393)

Answer (score 0):

The solution with best performance is using `Either`. It is similar to [Cerberus's `Vec` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59852696/955091), except that `Vec` is replaced by `Left` and `Right`, as mentioned in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50204370/955091), for better performance.

```rust
fn to_either(
    result: Result<Vec<MyStruct>, Error>,
) -> impl Iterator<Item = Result<MyStruct, Error>> {
    match result {
        Ok(vec) => Right(vec.into_iter().map(Ok)),
        Err(e) => Left(std::iter::once(Err(e))),
    }
}


fn either_collect(my_structs: &[MyStruct], err_value: u64) -> Result<Vec<MyStruct>, Error> {
    my_structs
            .iter()
            .map(|my_struct| produce_result(&my_struct, err_value))
            .flat_map(to_either)
            .collect::<Result<Vec<MyStruct>, Error>>()
}
```

Also `Box` can be used as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/29760740/955091 .

Below is an updated benchmark including all the solutions

```rust
#![feature(test)]
extern crate test;
use test::{black_box, Bencher};
use either::*;

struct Error;

struct MyStruct(u64);

fn produce_result(item: &MyStruct, err_value: u64) -> Result<Vec<MyStruct>, Error> {
    if item.0 == err_value {
        Err(Error)
    } else {
        Ok((0..item.0).map(MyStruct).collect())
    }
}


fn to_box_iterator(
    result: Result<Vec<MyStruct>, Error>,
) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = Result<MyStruct, Error>>> {
    match result {
        Ok(vec) => Box::new(vec.into_iter().map(Ok)),
        Err(e) => Box::new(std::iter::once(Err(e))),
    }
}


fn to_either(
    result: Result<Vec<MyStruct>, Error>,
) -> impl Iterator<Item = Result<MyStruct, Error>> {
    match result {
        Ok(vec) => Left(vec.into_iter().map(Ok)),
        Err(e) => Right(std::iter::once(Err(e))),
    }
}


fn either_collect(my_structs: &[MyStruct], err_value: u64) -> Result<Vec<MyStruct>, Error> {
    my_structs
            .iter()
            .map(|my_struct| produce_result(&my_struct, err_value))
            .flat_map(to_either)
            .collect::<Result<Vec<MyStruct>, Error>>()
}

fn box_collect(my_structs: &[MyStruct], err_value: u64) -> Result<Vec<MyStruct>, Error> {
    my_structs
            .iter()
            .map(|my_struct| produce_result(&my_struct, err_value))
            .flat_map(to_box_iterator)
            .collect::<Result<Vec<MyStruct>, Error>>()
}

fn internal_collect(my_structs: &[MyStruct], err_value: u64) -> Result<Vec<MyStruct>, Error> {
    my_structs
            .iter()
            .map(|my_struct| produce_result(&my_struct, err_value))
            .flat_map(|result| match result {
                Ok(vec) => vec.into_iter().map(|item| Ok(item)).collect(),
                Err(er) => vec![Err(er)],
            })
            .collect::<Result<Vec<MyStruct>, Error>>()
}

fn external_collect(my_structs: &[MyStruct], err_value: u64) -> Result<Vec<MyStruct>, Error> {
    Ok(my_structs
            .iter()
            .map(|my_struct| produce_result(&my_struct, err_value))
            .collect::<Result<Vec<_>, _>>()?
            .into_iter()
            .flatten()
            .collect())
}

#[bench]
pub fn internal_collect_start_error(b: &mut Bencher) {
    let my_structs: Vec<_> = black_box((0..1000).map(MyStruct).collect());
    b.iter(|| internal_collect(&my_structs, 0));
}

#[bench]
pub fn box_collect_start_error(b: &mut Bencher) {
    let my_structs: Vec<_> = black_box((0..1000).map(MyStruct).collect());
    b.iter(|| box_collect(&my_structs, 0));
}

#[bench]
pub fn either_collect_start_error(b: &mut Bencher) {
    let my_structs: Vec<_> = black_box((0..1000).map(MyStruct).collect());
    b.iter(|| either_collect(&my_structs, 0));
}

#[bench]
pub fn external_collect_start_error(b: &mut Bencher) {
    let my_structs: Vec<_> = black_box((0..1000).map(MyStruct).collect());
    b.iter(|| external_collect(&my_structs, 0));
}

#[bench]
pub fn internal_collect_end_error(b: &mut Bencher) {
    let my_structs: Vec<_> = black_box((0..1000).map(MyStruct).collect());
    b.iter(|| internal_collect(&my_structs, 999));
}

#[bench]
pub fn box_collect_end_error(b: &mut Bencher) {
    let my_structs: Vec<_> = black_box((0..1000).map(MyStruct).collect());
    b.iter(|| box_collect(&my_structs, 999));
}

#[bench]
pub fn either_collect_end_error(b: &mut Bencher) {
    let my_structs: Vec<_> = black_box((0..1000).map(MyStruct).collect());
    b.iter(|| either_collect(&my_structs, 999));
}

#[bench]
pub fn external_collect_end_error(b: &mut Bencher) {
    let my_structs: Vec<_> = black_box((0..1000).map(MyStruct).collect());
    b.iter(|| external_collect(&my_structs, 999));
}

#[bench]
pub fn internal_collect_no_error(b: &mut Bencher) {
    let my_structs: Vec<_> = black_box((0..1000).map(MyStruct).collect());
    b.iter(|| internal_collect(&my_structs, 1000));
}

#[bench]
pub fn box_collect_no_error(b: &mut Bencher) {
    let my_structs: Vec<_> = black_box((0..1000).map(MyStruct).collect());
    b.iter(|| box_collect(&my_structs, 1000));
}

#[bench]
pub fn either_collect_no_error(b: &mut Bencher) {
    let my_structs: Vec<_> = black_box((0..1000).map(MyStruct).collect());
    b.iter(|| either_collect(&my_structs, 1000));
}

#[bench]
pub fn external_collect_no_error(b: &mut Bencher) {
    let my_structs: Vec<_> = black_box((0..1000).map(MyStruct).collect());
    b.iter(|| external_collect(&my_structs, 1000));
}
```

Result:

```
cargo bench
```

```
  Downloaded either v1.8.1
  Downloaded 1 crate (16.0 KB) in 0.24s
   Compiling either v1.8.1
   Compiling my-project v0.1.0 (/home/runner/DarksalmonLiquidPi)
    Finished bench [optimized] target(s) in 4.63s
     Running unittests src/main.rs (target/release/deps/my_project-03c6287d7b53ee50)

running 12 tests
test box_collect_end_error        ... bench:   9,439,159 ns/iter (+/- 7,009,221)
test box_collect_no_error         ... bench:   9,538,551 ns/iter (+/- 7,923,652)
test box_collect_start_error      ... bench:          81 ns/iter (+/- 178)
test either_collect_end_error     ... bench:   4,266,292 ns/iter (+/- 6,008,125)
test either_collect_no_error      ... bench:   3,341,910 ns/iter (+/- 6,344,290)
test either_collect_start_error   ... bench:          41 ns/iter (+/- 53)
test external_collect_end_error   ... bench:     209,960 ns/iter (+/- 663,883)
test external_collect_no_error    ... bench:  10,074,473 ns/iter (+/- 4,737,417)
test external_collect_start_error ... bench:          17 ns/iter (+/- 55)
test internal_collect_end_error   ... bench:   8,860,670 ns/iter (+/- 6,148,916)
test internal_collect_no_error    ... bench:   8,564,756 ns/iter (+/- 6,842,558)
test internal_collect_start_error ... bench:          44 ns/iter (+/- 165)

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 12 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 69.52s
```

The benchmark can be found at https://replit.com/@Atry/DarksalmonLiquidPi